# How to access text from a single button in a class of buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a calculator app and I'm trying to do some stuff with jQuery. Right now, I've built all the HTML and CSS, all that is left is the JS. I'm trying to build it so that when I click a button which has a number(I've given all of those a class of 'num' and an id like 0,1,2 and so on) it pushes this number into an array, but in order to make it simple I'd like a way to get the text only of that specific 'num' I clicked, not all of them. I already tried the jQuery .text() method but it pushed all the numbers into the array. Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to do it specifically for each button?

Comment: Is better to show us the code instead of describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get a class or id or other values in an HTML Element, you need [listen an event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) for the element, for example:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    // todo
});
```

For this what you ask, you can try to get a [data property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in the buttons:

```
<button data-number="1">1</button>
<button data-number="2">2</button>
<button data-number="3">3</button>
...
```

And in the function of listener:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    const num = $(this).data('number'); 
    // num = value of 'data-number' property of button clicked
});
```

Or simply get a content of buttons like:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    const num = $(this).text(); 
    // num = text of button clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use several `<button value="1"><button> ...` and so on for all your buttons in the calculator.

Then you can add a eventDelegated listener in the container of such buttons, and capture the value of the pressed button.

```
<div class="numpad">
  <button value="1"><button>
  <button value="2"><button>
  <button value="3"><button>
  ...
</div>
```

And the jquery to catch it could be like this.

```
$('.numpad').on('click', 'button', function (ev) {
  $(this).val(); // holds the number
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do some sort of event listener for the click event. When that event is triggered, a callback method will run. This callback-method will receive something called an Event. This object has information about the thing that caused the event. I don't know exacly how your buttons are built up, but something along these lines should be possible:

```
$('.num').click(function(event){
    var clickedButton = event.target;
    var buttonText = $(clickedButton).text();
    var number = parseInt(buttonText, 10);
    console.log('clicked number ' + number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Plain JavaScript
var array=[]
var d = document.getElementByTagName("button");
for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{
    d[i].addEventListener("click",_pushIntoArray());
}
function _pushIntoArray(e)
{
    array.push(parseInt(this.textContent()));
}


Using Jquery
$("button").on("click",function()
{
  array.push(this.text());
}
```

you can also use the setAttribute / getAttribute method

Answer (score 0):

I would use delegate to listen for button clicks and data attributes for the numbers since the purpose of an ID is not to store data. Here is a working example.

```js
var numberArray = [];

$('.buttons-wrapper').delegate('.num', 'click', function() {
 var currentNumber = $(this).data('number');

 numberArray.push(currentNumber);
 console.log(numberArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons-wrapper">
 <button class="num" data-number="1">1</button>
 <button class="num" data-number="2">2</button>
 <button class="num" data-number="3">3</button>
 <button class="num" data-number="4">4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arryNum=[];

$(".num").on("click",function(){
  $('.led').empty();
  var num=$(this).attr("data-num");
  arryNum.push(num);
  $.each(arryNum,function(key,value){
  $('.led').append(value);
  });
});
```

```css
.parent{
width:200px;
height:250px;
border: solid 1px gray;
padding:10px;
}
.parent .led{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
}
.parent .nums{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.parent .nums .num{
  width:27%;
  height:30px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background-color:#E1ECF4;
   margin:5px;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   padding-top:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.parent .nums .num:hover{
 
  background-color:#BCD4E6;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="led"></div>
<div class="nums">
<div data-num="1" class="num">1</div>
<div data-num="2" class="num">2</div>
<div data-num="3" class="num">3</div>
<div data-num="4" class="num">4</div>
<div data-num="5" class="num">5</div>
<div data-num="6" class="num">6</div>
<div data-num="7" class="num">7</div>
<div data-num="8" class="num">8</div>
<div data-num="9" class="num">9</div>
</div>
</div>
```